# Simulating Order Data For a Unit Test

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, unit-tests, phpunit

I am currently writing my first unit test. The basis of the test is I get all of the order information along with the items and create a JSON object from it. Is there a way to create dummy items and orders with preset data?

Comment: You're looking for "fixtures"

Answer (score 8):

You should distinguish between unit and integration tests.

### Unit Test

In a unit test the class under test should get the order data from a collaborator that you can inject as a mock, for example the `OrderRepositoryInterface`.

### Integration Test

If you want to get test order data from the database, consider writing an integration test instead of a unit test.

Then use the `@magentoDataFixture Magento/Sales/_files/order.php` annotation to create a test order fixture for the test.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/testing/guide/integration/annotations/magento-data-fixture/) you will find some more information about test fixtures